# Configure client_id as mandatory param for password grant type

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

What is the proper way to make `client_id` a mandatory param for `password` grant type?
Using this request I want to make client_id a mandatory value and let the OAuth2 framework to compare it with the result returned into the method `loadClientByClientId`

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/engine/oauth/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cXdlcnR5' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'username=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'password=qwerty' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=some_value' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=read_profile'
```

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Why do you think that the `client_id` isn't mandatory?

Comment: Yes, I agree, I don't know a single implementation of Oauth2 where the clientId is not mandatory. And it's good like this, because this wouldn't make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try implementing a custom `OAuth2RequestValidator` with method `validateScope(TokenRequest tokenRequest, ...)` from the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/OAuth2RequestValidator.html)

> Ensure that the client has requested a valid set of scopes.

which has access to `TokenRequest.getRequestParameters()`

**EDIT**
See also the docs for the [TokenEndpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.html)

> Clients must be authenticated (...) to access this endpoint, and the client id is extracted from the authentication token. (...)